# squid3 blocks url by letters

Tags: regex, squid

I have problem with regex used in blocking URLS in Squid.

```
acl porn url_regex "/etc/squid3/porn.txt"
http_access deny porn
```

porn.txt looks like that

```
.sex.com
.redtube.com
```

problem is that this is REGEX rule, and at this point it means, that Squid will be block all URLs containing same letters for example

```
www.SamE-Xantipa.COM -> contain .sex.com  
www.REaDy-for-shop-TUBEs.COM -> contain .redtube.com
```

I don't know REGEX syntanx, and don't know how rewrite text file to search only WHOLE TEXT only

Comment: Perhaps, [this link to SquidGuard regex examples](http://www.squidguard.org/Doc/Examples/08.expressionlist) can be of help.

Comment: probably not... because I don't understand syntax... so I can't read what it do... And I have self words (domain) to block... there is noone of them. Could you rewrite for me by me mentiones URLs? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the dots!

A dot "." in regex actually can be "anything".

You need to put the inverted dashes.

So, instead of:

```
.sex.com
.redtube.com
```

You have to put:

```
\.sex\.com
\.redtube\.com
```

I also recommend you to block this way to cover all the possibilities:

```
^http://.*\.*sex\.com/*.*
^http://.*\.*redtube\.com/*.*
```

Let me explain what are you telling to squid to do with this regex:

> ^ = this is the beginning of the url
>        http:// = is the protocol that is always required
>        . = anything, for example, can be a subdomain or a www
>   * = the expression BEFORE (the subdomain or www) can happen or not
>   \ = the next char is not "anything" but a real dot
>        . = the real dot...
>   * = ...that can happen or not
>        sex = the domain
>        . = next char is a real real dot again
>        com = top level domain
>        /* = a dash that can happen or not (covering all the possible websites configurations here)
>        .* = anything can happen or not after the last dash (/index.php, blah blah)

I hope this helps you to understand a little about regex and how to block websites efficently!

Answer (score 0):

You can block by domains:

```
acl porn dstdomain -i "/etc/squid3/porn.txt"
http_access deny porn
```

Or block by Regex:

```
acl porn url_regex -i "/etc/squid3/porn.txt"
http_access deny porn
```

Where /etc/squid3/porn.txt file content could be:

```
domains\.com
www\.porn\.net
porn\.com
```